# Can I search the internet from Ubuntu's search feature (Unity Desktop)?

Tags: unity

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 and I am using the Unity desktop environment. I would like to know if there is a way to search the internet right from the search feature on the desktop (the feature that is similar to Windows' "start menu").  If so, how do I do this exactly?

Comment: Which start menu? Neither Gnome nor Unity have that thing.

Comment: the start menu : https://ibb.co/Z1DdGHV

Comment: NOT a start menu and no, it doesn't search the internet (Gnome) or presents some possibly relevant results (Unity).

Comment: what are you trying to say?

Comment: how do you call it if it's not a start menu?

Comment: You mean like Microsoft Windows 10 start menu?

Comment: In Unity it is called "Dash".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The desktop search features of both Unity and Gnome are not internet Search Engines.

Searches will return only a limited set of results from specific trusted sources, mostly local to your machine, and mostly about locating (or installing) whatever application you seem to be asking about.

To search the internet, use your web browser.